# Use `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d` to add items to the PATH in macOS Sierra?

Tags: osx, zsh, path, etc

From what I have gleaned in various places with discussions about `/usr/libexec/path_helper` and all, apparently the modern way to add items to the environment variable `PATH` in macOS Sierra 10.12 is to either:

- Edit the `/etc/paths` file
- Add file(s) to be read from the `/etc/paths.d` directory.

My Questions:

- Which is more kosher on modern macOS?
- If the better or more common way is dropping files into the `paths.d` directory, what should be the names and content of those files? Any examples?
- I am using `zsh` rather than `bash`. Does that make a difference?
- Are these two options unique to macOS? Or do they appear in BSD or other Unix-like systems?

Comment: Still waiting for an answer for the last bullet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `/etc/paths.d`. The primary reason is that `/etc/paths` will be modified and/or replaced by system upgrades. `/etc/paths.d/` items will not. Files are generally named with the pattern `index-source`. E.g., `99-mypaths`. Paths are appended in order*. It's a lot easier to simply add/remove a file than programmatically editing one idempotently without bugs.

The default `csh.login`, `profile`, and `zprofile` on macOS all load `path_helper`.

---

* Probably ASCII order, but maybe LOCALE order.